# load average from netapp filer

Tags: netapp

i'm currently trying to monitor the 5-min system load average from a netapp filer, via snmp or ontapi apis.
currently i'm running a cron job every 5 minutes and calculate the average percent, but i'm wondering if there's a better approach like it's working on most unix systems, to get the values for 1, 5, 15 minutes... didn't find anything on google and "netapp now", but maybe i missed it...

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with using PowerShell, you can use the [DataONTAP PowerShell Toolkit](https://communities.netapp.com/docs/DOC-6138) and the `Invoke-NaSysstat` cmdlet to get all sorts of performance information:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-NaSysstat -Count 3 -SampleIntervalSeconds 5

  CPU   NFS  CIFS  HTTP   FCP iSCSI  RdOps  WrOps TotOps  NetRcvd  NetSent   DiskRd   DiskWr   RdLat   WrLat  TotLat
  ---   ---  ----  ----   --- -----  -----  ----- ------  -------  -------   ------   ------   -----   -----  ------
   1%     0     1     0     0    12      0     12     12   130 KB     5 KB   158 KB   559 KB     0.0     0.1     0.1
   1%     0     0     0     0    18      0     17     17   178 KB     6 KB     6 KB     6 KB     0.0     0.1     0.1
   1%     0     2     0     0    15      4     11     16   125 KB   110 KB   164 KB   681 KB     0.1     0.1     0.1
```

That information is then easy to export to csv or xml for consuming in other programs (like excel).

If you are using the ONTAPI API's, look at the `perf-object-*` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your operating system is Linux, in this case, look for the oid of the metric LoadAverage and you can guet it's value directly via snmp request(snmpwalk/snmpget) without any additional script

Comment: no, it's a netapp filer and has some proprietary os, based on a bsd kernel. the standard unix oids won't work

Comment: The SNMP OID's are publically documented [here](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/789/NETWORK-APPLIANCE-MIB.html), meaning you can query directly from snmpwalk/snmpget. Personally, I log everything from our NetApp appliance using [Cacti](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/netapp-filer-cacti-template.php)

Answer (score 0):

The traditional unix "load average" value is not available on netapp.  You can see CPU percentages (either average or max).